# How do I get the buttons on the main page to change to the other views?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, rss

The code takes an rss feed parses it then displays it in a linkedlist using an arrayadapter, what i'm trying to do it load the linked list onto the other views, then when the button is clicked switch to the views where the feed will be displayed as a list.

The onCreate method:

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.current);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setContentView(R.layout.current);
            Log.e("Layout= ","Current");
        }
    });
    try
    { 
        setContentView(R.layout.current);
        listv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvst);
        // Get the data from the XML stream as a string
        result =  sourceListingString(sourceListingURL);

        // Do some processing of the data to get the individual parts of the       XML stream
        // At some point put this processing into a separate thread of execution
        RoadWorkslisting = parseData(result);
        // Display the string in the TextView object just to demonstrate this capability
        ArrayAdapter<RoadWorks> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<RoadWorks>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,RoadWorkslisting);
        listv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
    catch(IOException ae)
    {
        // Handle error
        response.setText("Error");
        // Add error info to log for diagnostics
        errorText.setText(ae.toString());
    } 

   final Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.planned);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setContentView(R.layout.planned);
            Log.e("Layout= ","Planned");
        }
    });


            try
                {

                setContentView(R.layout.planned);
                listv2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvst2);

                    // Get the data from the XML stream as a string
                    result2 =  sourceListingString2(sourceListingURL2);

                        // Do some processing of the data to get the individual parts of the XML stream
                        // At some point put this processing into a separate thread of execution
                        PlannedRoadWorkslisting = parseData2(result2);
                            // Display the string in the TextView object just to demonstrate this capability
                            ArrayAdapter<PlannedRoadWorks> arrayAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<PlannedRoadWorks>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, PlannedRoadWorkslisting);
                                listv2.setAdapter(arrayAdapter2);
                                setContentView(R.layout.main);
                }
                catch(IOException ae)
                    {
                        // Handle error
                        response.setText("Error");
                            // Add error info to log for diagnostics
                        errorText.setText(ae.toString());
                    } 
            }
```

Main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/cyan"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/planned"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:text="@string/planned" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/current"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:text="@string/current" />


    </LinearLayout>
```

Current.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView
android:id="@+id/lvst"
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

</ListView>
```

Planned.xml

```
<ListView
android:id="@+id/lvst2" 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<!-- lvst is the planned roadworks -->
</ListView>
```

Comment: specifically calling out your question helps others help you

Comment: Start a new activity or a fragment, dont call setContentView twice.